# How to implement initialization with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, initialization, android-asynctask, game-engine

I would like to initialize all the components of the game engine with the AsyncTask. Could somebody guide me how this would be done?

I'd like something like this:
1. Before the code runs, set a splash screen (.xml)
2. run the initialization code
3. once all done, run the load screen of the game

Here's my current code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display splash screen
        if(this.splashScreen != null) {
            // .xml
            setContentView(this.splashScreen);
        }

        // Do all the initialization

        // Acquire a wakeLock to prevent the phone from sleeping
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");

        // Setup all the Game Engine components 
        gameEngineLog = new WSLog("WSGameEngine");
        gameEngineLog.setLogType(this.gameEngineLogType);
        gameLog = new WSLog(this.gameLogTAG);
        gameLog.setLogType(this.gameLogType);
        io = new FileIO(this, getAssets());
        audio = new Audio(this);
        wsScreen = new WSScreen(this, this.screenResizeType, this.customTopYGap, this.customLeftXGap, this.gameScreenWidth, this.gameScreenHeight);
        graphics = new Graphics(this, wsScreen.getGameScreen(), wsScreen.getGameScreenextended());
        renderView = new RenderView(this, wsScreen.getGameScreen(), wsScreen.getGameScreenextended(), FPS, maxFrameskippes);
        input = new Input(this, renderView, logGameEngineInputLog);
        networkSocket = new NetworkSocket(this);

        this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Completed initialization");
        setContentView(renderView);

        // Check that the developer has initialized the assets
        if(this.assets == null) {
            this.gameEngineLog.w(classTAG, "The assets for the game haven't been defined!");
        }

        this.getNetworkSocket().useAnalytics(this.analyticsAppAPIKey);
        this.getNetworkSocket().useServerCommunication(this.serverCommunicationAppID, this.serverCommunicationClientKey);
        this.getNetworkSocket().useFacebookCommunicaiton(this.facebookCommunicationAppID);

        // Check if server communication should be initialized
        if(this.networkSocket.getUseOfServerCommunication() == true) {
            this.networkSocket.getServerCommunication().initialize(this, this.networkSocket.getServerCommunicationAppID(), this.networkSocket.getServerCommunicationClientKey()); 
        }

        // Check if facebook communication should be initialized
        if(this.networkSocket.getUseFacebookCommunication() == true) {
            this.networkSocket.getFacebookCommunication().initialize(this.networkSocket.getFacebookCommunicationAppID(), true);
        }

        // Start the Load screen
        // Once all of this code has been executed, the class that extends this class calls "setScreen(new LoadScreen(this));" to set the LoadScreen, which
        // loads all the assets of the game

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? : http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation the class exposes four methods that you can use to implement your application loading logic:

> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task is
> executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
> by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread
> immediately after  onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is
> used to perform background computation that can take a long time.
>
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call
> to publishProgress(Progress...). This method is used to display any
> form of progress in the user interface while the background
> computation is still executing.
>
> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
> computation finishes.  The result of the background computation is
> passed to this step as a parameter.

Following the documentation, you can start your async task in your main Activity. In the onPreExecute method you can display your splash screen.

In the doInBackGround method insert the code that does all the loading stuff. If you want to provide the user with some information about the loading state you can use inside this method publishProgress to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.

Finally in onPostExecute method you can remove the splashscreen and run the load screen of the game.

have a look also at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) example.

Answer (score 0):

Long winded answer, bear with me.

You'll have to do a few things to get what you want.

First separate your Activities instead of calling setContentView multiple times.

Then set up a domain object that is your 'Game settings' so you can load that, initializing all it's fields.

Also have a configuration object to load your settings.

In the example below I haven't loaded all your fields but I hope you get the point.

The final outcome would be something like this:

First Activity:

```
package com.blundell.tut.ui;

import com.blundell.tut.R;
import com.blundell.tut.domain.Config;
import com.blundell.tut.task.LoadingTask;
import com.blundell.tut.task.LoadingTask.LoadingTaskFinishedListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements LoadingTaskFinishedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the splash screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        // Find the progress bar
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_progress_bar);
        // Start your loading
        new LoadingTask(progressBar, this, getAssets(), new Config()).execute("www.google.co.uk"); // Pass in whatever you need a url is just an example we don't use it in this tutorial
    }

    // This is the callback for when your async task has finished
    @Override
    public void onTaskFinished(GameDomain result) {
            // The result object is your loaded files!
        completeSplash();
    }

    private void completeSplash(){
        startApp();
        finish(); // Don't forget to finish this Splash Activity so the user can't return to it!
    }

    private void startApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then the ASyncTask that does the loading:

```
package com.blundell.tut.task;

import com.blundell.tut.domain.Config;
import com.blundell.tut.domain.GameDomain;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, GameDomain> {

    public interface LoadingTaskFinishedListener {
        void onTaskFinished(GameDomain domain); // If you want to pass something back to the listener add a param to this method
    }

    private static final int NUM_OF_TASKS = 2;

    // This is the progress bar you want to update while the task is in progress
    private final ProgressBar progressBar;
    // This is the listener that will be told when this task is finished
    private final LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener;

    private final AssetManager assets;

    private final Config config;

    /**
     * A Loading task that will load some resources that are necessary for the app to start
     * @param progressBar - the progress bar you want to update while the task is in progress
     * @param finishedListener - the listener that will be told when this task is finished
     */
    public LoadingTask(ProgressBar progressBar, LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener, AssetManager assets, Config config) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.finishedListener = finishedListener;
        this.assets = assets;
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    protected GameDomain doInBackground(String... params) {
        GameDomain gameDomain = new GameDomain();
        Log.i("Tutorial", "Starting task with url: "+params[0]);
        if(resourcesDontAlreadyExist()){
            downloadResources(gameDomain);
        }

        return gameDomain;
    }

    private boolean resourcesDontAlreadyExist() {
        // Here you would query your app's internal state to see if this download had been performed before
        // Perhaps once checked save this in a shared preference for speed of access next time
        return true; // returning true so we show the splash every time
    }


    private void downloadResources(GameDomain gameDomain) {
        // We are just imitating some process thats takes a bit of time (loading of resources / downloading)
            int count = NUM_OF_TASKS;

            // Do some long loading things

            // Setup all the Game Engine components
           gameDomain.setGameEngineLog("WSGameEngine", config.LOG_TYPE);

           updateProgress(count--);

           gameDomain.setAssets(assets);

           updateProgress(count--);
    }

    public void updateProgress(int count) {
        // Update the progress bar after every step
        int progress = (int) ((NUM_OF_TASKS / (float) count) * 100);
        publishProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]); // This is ran on the UI thread so it is ok to update our progress bar ( a UI view ) here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(GameDomain result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        finishedListener.onTaskFinished(result); // Tell whoever was listening we have finished
    }
}
```

Then the object you are instantiating:

```
public class GameDomain {

    private WSLog gameEngineLog;
    private FileIO io;

    public void setGameEngineLog(String name, String logType){
         gameEngineLog = new WSLog(name);
         gameEngineLog.setLogType(logType);
    }

    public void setAssets(AssetManager assets) {
         io = new FileIO(assets);
    }

}
```

and also your Config:

```
package com.blundell.tut.domain;

public class Config {
    public String LOG_TYPE = "logType";
}
```

Finally your WakeLock should be 'got' in each activity onCreate and released in 'onPause'

Comment: I can't get it to work like I want it to, I got it to initialize everything, yet setContentView() has no effect and doesn't display the splash screen for some reason.

Comment: I ripped this out from my blog post here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/   You should split your splash screen and your main activity into two separate Activitys, setContentView should defiently display something